# Relocating rectangle on picturebox zoom

Tags: c#, visual-studio, image-resizing, rectangles

I've a pictureBox inside a panel which allows me to zoom-in and zoom-out pictureBox on mouseWheel event. The problem I'm facing right now is, when I zoom-In and Zoom-Out I'm not able to set the location of the rectangle with respect to the new pictureBox size, as we can see in the images - [Resized Image, Zoom-Out](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iOlQw.jpg), [Resized Image, Zoom-In](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HhmGs.jpg) (Not able to upload more pictures due to less reputation). Right now I can draw multiple rectangles on the puctureBox and the rectangles are stored in rectList, rectList is a variable of RectangleList which is a custom class which contains Rectangle. 
I referred to [How to make a rectangle move when PictureBox is resized](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15305076/how-to-make-a-rectangle-move-when-picturebox-is-resized) for calculating the new location for each rectangle drawn, but no success. Please help me to find the new location as I'm not able to find a way to calculate new location.

Below is the code on MouseWheel event.

```
private void PictureBox1_MouseWheel(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Delta != 0)
        {
            if (e.Delta <= 0)
            {
                //set minimum size to zoom
                if (pictureBox1.Width < 350)
                    return;
            }
            else
            {
                //set maximum size to zoom
                if (pictureBox1.Width > 10000)
                    return;
            }

            int[] oldRectX = new int[rectList.Count];
            int[] oldRectY = new int[rectList.Count];
            int oldPictureBoxWidth = pictureBox1.Width;
            int oldPictureBoxHeight = pictureBox1.Height;

            for (int i = 0; i < rectList.Count; i++)
            {
                oldRectX[i] = rectList[i].rectangle.X;
                oldRectY[i] = rectList[i].rectangle.Y;
            }

            pictureBox1.Width += Convert.ToInt32(pictureBox1.Width * e.Delta / 1000);
            pictureBox1.Height += Convert.ToInt32(pictureBox1.Height * e.Delta / 1000);

            for (int i = 0; i < rectList.Count; i++)
            {
                rectList[i].rectangle.Width += Convert.ToInt32(rectList[i].rectangle.Width * e.Delta / 1000);
                rectList[i].rectangle.Height += Convert.ToInt32(rectList[i].rectangle.Height * e.Delta / 1000);

                rectList[i].rectangle.X = Convert.ToInt32(oldRectX[i] * (pictureBox1.Width / oldPictureBoxWidth));
                rectList[i].rectangle.Y = Convert.ToInt32(oldRectY[i] * (pictureBox1.Height / oldPictureBoxHeight));
                rectList[i].SetNewLocationOfSubRectList();
            }
            pictureBox1.Location = new Point((pictureBox1.Parent.ClientSize.Width / 2) - (pictureBox1.Width / 2), (pictureBox1.Parent.ClientSize.Height / 2) - (pictureBox1.Height / 2)); // Set the pictureBox1 to Center
            if (pictureBox1.Width > panel1.Width || pictureBox1.Height > panel1.Height)
            {
                Cursor = Cursors.Hand;
                mouseModeEnum = MouseMode.PANNING;
            }
            else
            {
                mouseModeEnum = MouseMode.NONE;
                Cursor = Cursors.Default;
            }
            pictureBox1.Invalidate();
        }
    }
```

I tried calculating the percentage of the location as suggested in [How to make a rectangle move when PictureBox is resized](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15305076/how-to-make-a-rectangle-move-when-picturebox-is-resized) it worked, but not very satisfying as when I convert the percentage to location which is from double to int it truncates some of the decimal values. please let me know if there is any better way to do this.
my new code is

```
private void PictureBox1_MouseWheel(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Delta != 0)
        {
            if (e.Delta <= 0)
            {
                //set minimum size to zoom
                if (pictureBox1.Width < 350)
                    return;
            }
            else
            {
                //set maximum size to zoom
                if (pictureBox1.Width > 10000)
                    return;
            }

            double[] xLocPercent = new double[rectList.Count];
            double[] yLocPercent = new double[rectList.Count];
            double Width = pictureBox1.Width;
            double Height = pictureBox1.Height;

            for (int i = 0; i < rectList.Count; i++)
            {
                double X = rectList[i].rectangle.X;
                double Y = rectList[i].rectangle.Y;

                xLocPercent[i] = (X / Width) * 100;
                yLocPercent[i] = (Y / Height) * 100;
            }

            Width = pictureBox1.Width += Convert.ToInt32(pictureBox1.Width * e.Delta / 1000);
            Height = pictureBox1.Height += Convert.ToInt32(pictureBox1.Height * e.Delta / 1000);

            for (int i = 0; i < rectList.Count; i++)
            {
                rectList[i].rectangle.Width += Convert.ToInt32(rectList[i].rectangle.Width * e.Delta / 1000);
                rectList[i].rectangle.Height += Convert.ToInt32(rectList[i].rectangle.Height * e.Delta / 1000);
                rectList[i].rectangle.X = Convert.ToInt32((Width * xLocPercent[i]) / 100);
                rectList[i].rectangle.Y = Convert.ToInt32((Height * yLocPercent[i]) / 100);
                rectList[i].SetNewLocationOfSubRectList();
            }

            pictureBox1.Location = new Point((pictureBox1.Parent.ClientSize.Width / 2) - (pictureBox1.Width / 2), (pictureBox1.Parent.ClientSize.Height / 2) - (pictureBox1.Height / 2));

            if (pictureBox1.Width > panel1.Width || pictureBox1.Height > panel1.Height)
            {
                Cursor = Cursors.Hand;
                mouseModeEnum = MouseMode.PANNING;
            }
            else
            {
                mouseModeEnum = MouseMode.NONE;
                Cursor = Cursors.Default;
            }
            pictureBox1.Invalidate();
        }
    }
```

Comment: For any of those who are searching for solution this example might help.
I've made it myself if C#. [GitHub DrawingRectangle](https://github.com/tehsunnliu/DrawingRectangle)